# In diskpart, when I type "select disk 1", then select partition 1, I get "No partition selected"

Tags: windows, usb, command-line

In `diskpart`, when I type `select disk 1`, then `select partition 1`, I get

> No partition selected

The USB is FAT 32. Basically, I am trying to do set `id=af` on my flash drive.

Comment: Have you tried LIST PARTITION?  The drive might not be partitioned.

Answer (score 3):

Because the partition is already selected. You should see an asterisk `*` to the left of the listed partition.

Comment: "No partition selected" appears to be the exact opposite of "the partition is already selected".

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with the partition being listed with asterisc (selected) but could not select it and I had the no partition selected problem  and after reading the solutions here and in other places I removed the partition with clean and then re created it and made it active and then formatted the drive again in Disk Management. I still do not know yet how to  put system on it to make it bootable

I did

DISKPART> clean

to clean the partition... Then I used

DISKPART> create partition primary size=14366

( I got that buy doing 14(GB) *1024=14366 MB) and then I listed the partition

DISKPART> list partition 
and it listed the partition with asterisk like before and then I just made it active, without selecting it again and it worked

DISKPART> active

then I formatted the partition in the disk management in windows 7 (but I did not get the option of making the partition bootable) and then on checking the status again I got Healthy (Active Primary Partition)
I hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

If you select an object for a second time, diskpart still emits a message indicating that the object is selected. Harry's question is valid. What do you get when you select the Flash Drive and then `LIST PARTITION`?

Here's a transcript of a diskpart session, for reference:

```
DISKPART> list disk

  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online          596 GB    11 MB
  Disk 1    Online          954 MB      0 B

DISKPART> select disk 1

Disk 1 is now the selected disk.

DISKPART> list part

  Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset
  -------------  ----------------  -------  -------
  Partition 1    Primary            953 MB    64 KB

DISKPART> select part 1

Partition 1 is now the selected partition.

DISKPART> list part

  Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset
  -------------  ----------------  -------  -------
* Partition 1    Primary            953 MB    64 KB

DISKPART> sel part 1                             # Second Select Part

Partition 1 is now the selected partition.       # same "object selected" message

DISKPART> detail part

Partition 1
Type  : 0B
Hidden: No
Active: Yes
Offset in Bytes: 65536

  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
* Volume 4     E   NEW LABEL    FAT32  Removable    953 MB  Healthy

DISKPART> set ID=AF

DiskPart successfully set the partition ID.

DISKPART> list part

  Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset
  -------------  ----------------  -------  -------
* Partition 1    Primary            953 MB    64 KB

DISKPART> detail part

Partition 1
Type  : AF
Hidden: Yes
Active: Yes
Offset in Bytes: 65536

There is no volume associated with this partition.
```

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: I see the asterisk next to Partition 1, yet when I use the command `delete partition` I get the error "there are no partitions selected".

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to do something similar so this may help you:

I wanted to select the partition so that I could then delete it. This was necessary so that I could then use the windows version of `dd`.

I was not able to select the partition with the asterisk. I tried selecting another disk and another partition, but as soon as I selected the target disk again the partition 1 was auto-selected with the aterisk. Since all I wanted to do was delete the partition, I was able to use the [`clean`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731145.aspx) command within diskpart, so something like this:

```
diskpart

list disk
select disk 4 
clean
```

If you then run `detail disk` you will see that the status has changed to "unusable". I was then able to run my dd command from an image to this sd card.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get the list disk process as Geoff Duke said ? If you don't than I think there might be some problem with your hardware , And then again if you do then try selecting again and check for typing mistakes this happens a lot with me . Also if still nothing happens go to explorer and format directly from there and come back again and try with cmd.