# Weird!!! Where is my folder in flash memmory?

Tags: windows-7, memory-card

I have a Silicon-Power 4GB USB flash memory. I had some files and a directory named `ro0t` in it. but today while I can see the occupied size,  I can't the that directory!

I even change settings to show hidden files and system files!

The below images clearly explain my problem!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Even when I want to move these files, I receive this error :

[image]

Appreciate any help :)

Comment: Well, it does seem like your flash disk drive is corrupted. Filesystem perhaps. Have you tried formatting it?

Comment: The question is unclear, take note you may have to select a disk in diskpart to see the free space of the partition(s): http://superuser.com/questions/431349/in-diskpart-when-i-type-select-disk-1-then-select-partition-1-i-get-no-par

Comment: This sounds like a filesystem error caused by a hardware failure.

Comment: What I must do? I tested the flash memory in other computers too, and I have the same problem!

Comment: And again. Have you tried formatting it?

Comment: @LittleHelper Yes I format it successfully ! but I didn't want to repair it! I was wanted to know what is the origin of error!